# $\{e_n\}_{n=2}^\infty$ is a complete orthonormal system for $G:=\{f, e_2, e_3, \dots\}$ where $f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}e_n$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to prove the following:

> If $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is the standard basis of $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ and $f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}e_n$ then for $G:=\{f, e_2, e_3, \dots\}$ the set $\{e_n\}_{n=2}^\infty$ is a complete orthonormal system for $G$, yet is not a basis for $G$.

So the orthonormal part is immediate from the fact that it's a subset of the standard basis for $l^2(\mathbb{N})$, but I'm unable to show it is complete (i.e. the only orthogonal vectors are $0$). What I've done is the following:

Let $g\in G$ such that $\langle g, e_n \rangle=0$ for all $n\geq 2$. We will prove that $||g||^2=0$ which means $g=0$ and we are done.

Since $g\in G$, then there exist $\{\alpha_n\}_{n=2}^N$ and $\alpha_f$ such that $g=\sum_{n=2}^N\alpha_ne_n+\alpha_f f$.

So:

$\langle g,g\rangle = \sum_{n=2}^\infty\langle e_n,g\rangle +\alpha_f\langle f,g\rangle $

The first term is $0$. But when I open the second term I end up with $\overline{\alpha_f}\langle e_1,f\rangle$ which is not $0$.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: @DavidMitra That's for the "it's not a basis" part. I need to show that it's not complete first by definition.

Comment: Is $G$ a linear span?

Comment: @DavidMitra Yes, it is.

Comment: Let $g\in \ell^2$ and $g\perp e_n$ for $n\ge 2. $ Then $g=ae_1.$ But $e_1$ does not belong to the linear span of $\{f,e_2,e_3,\ldots \}.$ Hence $g$ belongs to this linear span only for $a=0,$ i.e. $g=0.$

Comment: Right before the "So", isn't easy to see $g$ is not orthogonal to $e_{N+1}$ if $\alpha_f\ne0$?

Comment: @DavidMitra But $g$ is, by assumption, orthogonal to all $e_m$ for $m\geq 2$ so that would include $e_{N+1}$, so that wouldn't depend on $\alpha_f$.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc but $g$ is in $G$, not $l^2$.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that $\alpha_f$ must be zero.

Comment: Are you able to explain why? I can't see it from $\langle g,e_{N+1}\rangle=0$

Comment: @Anon $G\subset \ell^2.$

Comment: The inner product with the sum is $0$, the inner product with $\alpha_f f$ is $\alpha_f/(N+1)$.

Comment: OK I completely misunderstood what you wrote earlier. I get it now. Thanks!